# Python - Impersonate currently logged user (from system user)

Tags: python, winapi, impersonation, python-2.6

I have to write a Python script on Windows (using win32 api), executed with system privileges. I need to impersonate the currently logged user to show him a popup (because system user can't).

So, I'm searching a way to do this operation. I find this method:
win32security.ImpersonateLoggedOnUser
but requires a handle that can be obtained with this method:
win32security.LogonUser

The last method however requires the user password, but I haven't. There is a way to get this handler (or another way to impersonate the currently logged user, or another way to show a popup from system user) without the user password? I'm the system user, so I have full privileges on the machine...

Thanks a lot and sorry for my bad english!
Federico

Comment: Actually it doesn't make any difference whether a process is running with system privileges or not, what matters is what Remote Desktop session the process is running in.  Impersonation won't help.  You have to launch a separate process (in the appropriate session) to interact with the user on your behalf.  There are existing questions and answers regarding this, though probably not in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Your script must be running as a service. I believe since Windows Vista you must have a separate app in the user session for the GUI.